# python replace remove one tab from each line

Tags: python

For example I've got a file with lines like this

```
\tline1\t
\t\tline2\t
\t\tline3
\tline4
```

I need to remove only first tab in the beginning of every string(and I don't care if there are more tabs in the line)
So the result suppose to look like this

```
line1\t
\tline2\t
\tline3
line4
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular expressions may help:

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile('^\t')  # match a tab in the beginning of the line
>>> pattern.sub('', '\tline1\t')
'line1\t'
>>> pattern.sub('', '\t\tline2\t')
'\tline2\t'
>>> pattern.sub('', 'line3\t')
'line3\t'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
s = "\thello"
s.replace("\t", "", 1)
```

Unsure if it's needed but this will handle stuff like `"hello\tworld" also, i.e. replace the first tab in the string disregarding where in the string it is